# n.integration.contentconnector.JcrContentConnector: Failed to obtain JCR id for fragment exception

Tags: magnolia

I have created content app on magnolia Author then publish the same to magnolia publish, my app is published but when I click on app icon in app launcherlayout, it give me exception

```
    2019-06-24 18:06:32,426 ERROR n.integration.contentconnector.JcrContentConnector: Failed to obtain JCR id for fragment: pastry
    javax.jcr.NoSuchWorkspaceException: pastry
        at info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.getSession(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:309) ~[magnolia-core-5.6.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.context.DefaultRepositoryStrategy.internalGetSession(DefaultRepositoryStrategy.java:61) ~[magnolia-core-5.6.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy.getSession(AbstractRepositoryStrategy.java:75) ~[magnolia-core-5.6.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.context.AbstractContext.getJCRSession(AbstractContext.java:124) ~[magnolia-core-5.6.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext.getJCRSession(MgnlContext.java:642) ~[magnolia-core-5.6.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.va

adin.integration.jcr.JcrItemUtil.getItemId(JcrItemUtil.java:177) ~[magnolia-ui-vaadin-integration-5.6.2.jar:?]
    at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.contentconnector.JcrContentConnector.getItemIdByUrlFragment(JcrContentConnector.java:114) [magnolia-ui-vaadin-integration-5.6.2.j
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the same content app on the public instance as well. Then, you can publish your content to the public instance. You've received this exception because the workspace is not present in the public instance.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! @Ducaz035 
but this is kind of Manual Process, how we automate through (CI/CD). let say we want to publish workspace from Dev Magnolia to Qa Magnolia then how it can be done ?

Comment: First, you should have similar setups in different environments. Then you can use normal publishing mechanisms to distribute it to various instances. There are other solutions for that but they are mostly in the Enterprise package such as https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Synchronization+module